# export pandas dataframe object to the console

Tags: pandas, io, dataframe

Is there a way to export/print/IO a pandas dataframe object to either the python console or ipython notebook output?

It would be nice if there is some IO mechanism that lets you quickly export a dataframe object so it can be copied to the clipboard and then pasted in another window. For example, if I'm trying to work through a problem with someone on Stackoverflow and want to quickly reproduce the dataframe for them it would be nice if you could quickly export/import it through copy/paste actions?

I've read through the IO documentation but not sure if there is anything like what I describe.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html

**Update 2:**

Try the following with the dataframe below:

1) Copy the dataframe and directly insert it into ipython WITHOUT using read_clipboad(). Call the dataframe df.

2) Now copy df to clipboard by df.to_clipboard()

3) Control P to paste in a text editor such as Notepad/Notepad++/SublimeText2

4) Select what was pasted in #3 and copy to clip board using Control C

5) Go back to ipython console and type in df2 = pd.read_clipboard()

Inspect df2 and notice that it is not the same as df. The data is misaligned and corrupt.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'BlahBlah0' : ['','','',''],
'BlahBlah1' : ['','','',''],
'BlahBlah2' : ['','','',''],
'BlahBlah3' : ['','','',''],
'BlahBlah4' : ['','','',''],
'BlahBlah5' : ['A','C','E','G'],
'BlahBlah6' : ['B','D','F','H'],
'BlahBlah7' : ['','','',''],
'BlahBlah8' : ['','','',''],
'BlahBlah9' : ['','','',''],
'BlahBlah10' : ['','','',''],
'BlahBlah11' : ['','','',''],
'Size1':[1,1,1,1], 
'Price1':[50,50,50,50],
'Size2':[2,2,2,2], 
'Price2':[75,75,75,75], 
'Size3':[4,4,4,4], 
'Price3':[100,100,100,100], 
'Size4':[8,8,8,8], 
'Price4':[125,125,125,125],
'Size5':[10,10,10,10], 
'Price5':[200,200,200,200],
'Size6':[5,5,5,5], 
'Price6':[250,250,250,250],
'Size7':[10,10,10,10], 
'Price7':[300,300,300,300]
},columns=['BlahBlah0', 
'BlahBlah1',
'BlahBlah2',
'BlahBlah3',
'BlahBlah4',
'BlahBlah5',
'BlahBlah6',
'BlahBlah7',
'BlahBlah8',
'BlahBlah9',
'BlahBlah10',
'BlahBlah11',
'Size1',
'Price1',
'Size2',
'Price2',
'Size3',
'Price3',
'Size4',
'Price4',
'Size5',
'Price5',
'Size6',
'Price6',
'Size7',
'Price7'] )
```

Answer (score 1):

see docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#io-clipboard

df.to_clipboard() exports to the clipboard. pd.read_clipboard() is the reverse.

Comment: Appreciate your quick reply. Thank you. So I came across these functions as well when I read through the documentation. However, I've had problems with the pd.read_clipboard(). I first did the df.to_clipboard(), pasted to notepad, then selected exactly what I pasted and copied to the clipboard. Then did a pd.read_clipboard(). However, the data is corrupt. The values that were in certain columns now appear in other columns and where previously there was valid data now show NaN. This does not appear to be stable feature.